# Cannot mark directories as "Resources" or "Templates" Content Root in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, project-structure

I created a new project in PyCharm Community Edition with a Python 2.7 venv. I would like to add a directory and mark it as Resources Content Root. However, in the Project structure settings, only "Sources Root" and "Excluded" are available.

In the documentation, I could not find any hint as to why "Resources" and "Templates" might be unavailable. Also, Google seems to tell me that I am the only one with this problem.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Do you use PyCharm Community or PyCharm Professional Edition?

Comment: I use PyCharm Community Edition, will edit the question.

Comment: It's available only in Professional one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could not find this documented anywhere, but this settles it. Did I miss something here? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html